# Can ping by IP, not by domain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, ping

I have an Apache2 web server with vhosts at 173.xxx.xxx.xx1, listening on port 80 & 443. One vhost I'm trying to access is `dev.REDACTED.com`.

I can ping the IP of the server:

```
~: ping 173.xxx.xxx.xx1
PING 173.xxx.xxx.xx1 (173.xxx.xxx.xx1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.xxx.xxx.xx1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.466 ms
64 bytes from 173.xxx.xxx.xx1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.555 ms
64 bytes from 173.xxx.xxx.xx1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.717 ms
64 bytes from 173.xxx.xxx.xx1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.445 ms
^C
--- 173.xxx.xxx.xx1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.445/0.545/0.717/0.110 ms
```

And I can `dig` the domain name (resolves correctly -- correct DNS):

```
~: dig dev.REDACTED.com

; <<>> DiG 9.4.2-P2.1 <<>> dev.REDACTED.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19685
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 10

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev.REDACTED.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dev.REDACTED.com.       769 IN  A   173.xxx.xxx.xx1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
REDACTED.com.       85729   IN  NS  ns5.mydyndns.org.
REDACTED.com.       85729   IN  NS  ns2.mydyndns.org.
REDACTED.com.       85729   IN  NS  ns4.mydyndns.org.
REDACTED.com.       85729   IN  NS  ns3.mydyndns.org.
REDACTED.com.       85729   IN  NS  ns1.mydyndns.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.mydyndns.org.   408 IN  A   204.13.248.76
ns1.mydyndns.org.   408 IN  AAAA    2600:2001::76
ns2.mydyndns.org.   51707   IN  A   204.13.249.76
ns2.mydyndns.org.   51707   IN  AAAA    2600:2002::76
ns3.mydyndns.org.   49856   IN  A   208.78.69.76
ns3.mydyndns.org.   49856   IN  AAAA    2600:2003::76
ns4.mydyndns.org.   50206   IN  A   91.198.22.76
ns4.mydyndns.org.   50196   IN  AAAA    2600:2004::76
ns5.mydyndns.org.   49118   IN  A   203.62.195.76
ns5.mydyndns.org.   49118   IN  AAAA    2600:2005::76

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 173.xxx.xxx.4#53(173.xxx.xxx.4)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 15 22:18:19 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 368
```

But I cannot `ping` the domain name, nor does the browser take me to the homepage when I visit the domain:

```
~: ping dev.REDACTED.com
PING dev.REDACTED.com (173.xxx.xxx.xx1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- dev.REDACTED.com ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 11004ms
```

It's not a local hosts issue, since I have tried pinging from several separate machines on different networks.

I'm disinclined to believe it's an Apache2 issue (since wouldn't it still respond to a ping, just not display the page??), but I'm happy to post whatever config files you might think relevant to the solution. Help!!

---

**UPDATE**: The real domain name is `dev.rdny.com`, and the real IP is `173.45.228.221`.

Comment: Why are you using sudo in the first ping (by IP address), and not in the second (by name)?

Comment: Aph, forgot to edit that out... on one server, I get funky a funky permission denied error if I try to run ping without sudo, but on all the other servers I tested this on, it wasn't an issue.

Comment: `chmod a+s /bin/ping` will fix that permissions problem.

Comment: You're probably going to have to give the real domain name, because there isn't enough information in your question to give anything more than a wild guess as to the actual cause.  We can investigate a real DNS entry and work out what's going on.

Comment: @womble - Ahh, ok. Updating with the real domain name & IP...

Comment: @neezer - dev.rdny.com resolves to 173.43.238.221, not 173.43.228.221.  do you have your dns pointed to the wrong address, perhaps?

Comment: And *that* is why we like unredacted questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ dig dev.rdny.com
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
dev.rdny.com.           1440    IN      A       173.45.238.221
```

"and the real IP is `173.43.228.221`"

/me sings "One of these things, is not like the other..."

Comment: The real IP in your question is now 173.45.228.221.  I'm still singing...

Comment: Well hooray! Yes, I typed in the wrong IP in my DNS hosting... I really shouldn't be setting up servers on 3 hours of sleep in the past two days... thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

```
dig dev.rdny.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> dev.rdny.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28062
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev.rdny.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dev.rdny.com.       1236    IN  A   173.45.238.221

;; Query time: 22 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.25#53(192.168.1.25)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 15 23:23:30 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46
```

Your External IP doesn't match what you mentioned.  Neither 173.43.228.221 or 173.45.238.221 replies to ping (nor does dev.rdny.com).  Also, trying to browse to any of those using http: or https:  fails.  I think you have other issues.